# Run gradle task of type Copy from gradle code

Tags: android, gradle

I have gradle task:

```
task copyDebugConfigJson(type: Copy) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    from 'some/file/dir/file.json'
    into 'some/other/file/dir/'
    rename ('file.json', "config.json') 
}
```

And I can invoke it from terminal like that:

```
./gradlew copyDebugConfigJson
```

and it works. But I would like to make it happen automatically during build so for example:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
           // somehow make copyDebugConfigJson task start there
        }
    }
}
```

Or anytime before app starts running I would like this copy to happen. In general I ask you how can start type:Copy task from gradle blocks.

Comment: not very familiar with android build workflow, what does buildTypes - debug closure do? is it configuration phase or execution phase?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your task run before compilation:

```
afterEvaluate {
  android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(copyDebugConfigJson)
  }
}
```